# How to mock realm-cocoa in swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, realm

I'm using [realm-cocoa](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) for my persistence layer. There is one of the classes depending on `realm`

```
class RealmMetaData : AbstractMetaData {
    var realm: RealmInterface
    var isFirstLaunch: Bool = false
    init(realm: RealmInterface = try! Realm()) {
        self.realm = realm
        let results = realm.objects(MyClass.self)
        self.isFirstLaunch = (results.count == 0)
        if (self.isFirstLaunch) {
            realm.write {
                realm.add(MyClass())
            }
        }
    }
    // some code
}


protocol RealmInterface {
    // using a protocol based approach of mocking
    func objects<T: Object>(type: T.Type) -> Results<T>
    func write(@noescape block: (() throws -> Void)) throws
    func add(object: Object)
}

extension Realm: RealmInterface {
    func add(object: Object) { self.add(object, update: false) }
    // there is a method for Realm with signature: add(object:Object, update:Bool = false)
    // but swift extension dose not permit default function parameter, hence the wrapping
}
```

Then in my test code, I can write a mocked version of `RealmInterface` and inject it to the `RealmMetaData` instance using [Constructor Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection).

When implementing the mocked `RealmInterface`, I found that's very difficult to mock the `objects` function to return an empty list. Because the return type of the function signature `Results<T>` is a type provided by the [Realm Framework](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) and there is no empty constructor available. Here is where I'm stuck.

That `Result<T>` is a class with `final` keyword so I also can't subclass it to use it's private methods to fetch an empty collection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First suggestion that comes to mind is to keep and manage in-memory Realm inside your test class and forward all this methods to it.

Comment: @Dmitry Yeah, that helped, thanks. Would you write this comment as an answer then I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in a comments you can just use an internal in-memory Realm inside your test class and forward all methods that return `Result<T>` to it.

Answer (score 0):

I end up returning my own protocol instead of results. So I have implementation of this protocol with `AnyRealmCollection<T>` and the other with just `[T]` so I easily mock it in tests without any in-memory Realm object.

Comment: Although I understand this approach, it's not good practice to alter your code to facilitate testing in this way.

Comment: @KevinR because of what?

Comment: My two cents, but altering code to facilitate introduces more complexity and therefor possible mistakes. Furthermore, changing implementations during testing can lead you to think the code runs fine when in reality the representation used in production code might lead to different results.

Comment: @KevinR thanks for response. I'm a bit surprised with it actually, because testing your logic in couple with Realm increases complexity, and in case of failure you don't know if it was your fault or library's one. Thus, I abstract code and decrease complexity. My implementation does not depend to the type of collection it sees, so when I hid it I actually gain that only my logic is being tested – that's exactly what I wanted, because it was unit test. (I have also integration tests which checks that realm integrates fine)